# Karma - Istanbul - code coverage report path

Tags: node.js, code-coverage, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, istanbul

I am using `karma` as a jasmine test runner, with [`instanbul`](http://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/) as a code coverage tool.
All works perfectly, one question though - is there any way I could change the path to the report that is created?

i.e. for Chrome I get `/coverage/Chrome%2035.0.1916%20(Windows%207)/index.html` ; I would much more happy with `/coverage/Chrome/index.html`

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your karma.conf.js:

```
    coverageReporter: {
        dir: 'coverage/',
        subdir: 'Chrome',
        file: 'index.html'
    }
```

EDIT: To have a subdir name based on the name of the browser used for the test:

```
    coverageReporter: {
        dir: 'coverage',
        subdir: function(browser) {
            return browser.toLowerCase().split(/[ /-]/)[0];
        },
        file: 'index.html'  
    }
```

Comment: this will stack everything under Chrome dir, what about multiple cases, i.e. firefox, opera etc..